# error for pandas installation and update of pip in python 3.5 windows

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

First of all I'm new to python and using 3.5 version when trying to install pandas using`pip install pandas`it is showing error as **pip is not recognized as an internal or external command** by using other command to install some packages,`py -3.5 -m pip install SomePackage`it shows me error **could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SomePackage** also ask's me update the pip version from 7.1.2 to 8.1.0 and when updating the pip `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` it shows me error **python is not recognized as an internal or external command**

Now how to install Pandas on my python 3.5?

Comment: Do you know how to set the system path on Windows? You probably need to add your python and python/scripts directory to it.

Comment: @PaulH I know where to set the path but what does "add your python and python/scripts directory to it."?? mean???

Comment: The python executable is somewhere on your computer. That folder containing python.exe needs to be in the path. Similarly the .../scripts subdirectory should probably be on your path as well.

Comment: thanx @PaulH error resolved

Answer (score 0):

You should try typing in python3 instead of python because, you are running v3.x on Python and the command python runs v2.7 according to me.